# Test the convergence of the improper integral

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I need to test the convergence of the integral $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{1-x} dx$$

Now, $f(x) = \frac{x^n}{1-x}$ and it has point of infinite discontinuity at $x = 1$ .
If we do the $\mu$ test, then, $$\lim_{x\to1} (1-x)^{1} \frac{x^n}{1-x} = 1$$ which is finite and non-zero. Here, $\mu = 1$ but the condition of convergence of the integral is $0<\mu<1$ , and here, since $\mu = 1$ , the integral diverges. I do not have a solution and this is all that I derived. Is my approach correct? If not, then what is?

Comment: Approach is correct, and yes, this integral diverges.

Comment: Sure there's no alternative way? Any other ways to prove the divergence?

Comment: Alternative approaches could be to try squeezing.  Note that: $$\int_a^1\frac{x^n}{1-x}~\mathrm dx>\int_a^1\frac{a^n}{1-x}~\mathrm dx$$ where the right integral diverges for any $a>0$.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @shiladityabasu there are often many, many ways to solve such problems, to list them all is usually a waste of effort. MSE is typically a place to seek out a solution, not really to have a discussion of the myriad approaches. If you are looking for an approach using a specific technique, you should indicate so in your question.

Comment: No no the primary and the only reason I posted thid was clarification that my approach was right. Because I had no way of checking the answers as there isn't one in the book. I was a little curious about the other approaches. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct.  Let me describe some intuition:  As $x\to 1^-$, the numerator of the integrand tends to $1$ while the denominator tends to zero.  Since the denominator is $1-x$ and $x\to 1^-$, the fraction blows up at the same rate that $\frac{1}{u}$ does as $u\to 0^+$.  So we should use the divergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{u}\,du$ to decide the divergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1-x}\,dx$.

Now, to be more formal: Make the substitution $u=1-x$.  This transforms $\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1-x}\,dx$ to $\int_0^1 \frac{(1-u)^n}{u}\,du$.  Using the binomial theorem, the integrand simplifies to a polynomial in $u$, plus $\frac{1}{u}$.  There is no question that the polynomial part is integrable on $0 \leq u \leq 1$.  So the convergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{(1-u)^n}{u}\,du$ is equivalent to the convergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{u}\,du$, and we know that this integral diverges.  Thus $\int_0^1 \frac{(1-u)^n}{u}\,du$ diverges, meaning that $\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1-x}\,dx$ diverges.